# Brother label printing COM reference error

Tags: vb.net, printing, com

I am having a horrible time with the Brother bpac SDK. I have an application and I am trying to print a label from it. It worked before but I do not know what is wrong now.

Here is the error I am getting: 
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {B940C105-7F01-46FE-BF41-E040B9BDA83D} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

Code:

```
   'Set up the path and template variables
    Dim path As String = "LabelTemplates\SolutionIDtemplate.lbx"

    'Create the bpac document
    Dim doc As New bpac.Document

    If doc.Open(path) <> False Then

        doc.GetObject("objID").Text = id
        doc.GetObject("objExpDate").Text = expDate
        doc.GetObject("objName").Text = name

        'Print the label
        doc.StartPrint("", bpac.PrintOptionConstants.bpoDefault)
        doc.PrintOut(copies, bpac.PrintOptionConstants.bpoDefault)
        doc.EndPrint()
        doc.Close()

    Else

        MessageBox.Show("Error: " + CStr(doc.ErrorCode))

    End If
```

NOTE: The class is in the registry and my project is set up to build as a 32 bit application. Everywhere I have looked says to go to Project > Properties > Build Tab > Target CPU = x86. I have done this but the problem still persists. Any help would be much appreciated because I have tried everything that I can think of.

Thanks in advance, 
Eli

Comment: Are you accessing it from a different machine or an upgraded(say Windows7 upgrade) machine?  There may be a different version registered you'd need to add or sometimes it's a matter of reRegistering the component, via RegSvr32, from the Wow64 folder

Comment: It is possible you installed the 64 bit bpac components and not the 32 bit ones?

Comment: I reregistered the DLL with regsvr32 already and that didn't help. I will check if on the drivers and verify that it is the 32 bit on Monday at work and will give an update. Any other suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I reinstalled the SDK and that seemed to work. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 8):

For future reference, do not forget to give your users b-pac client setup (can be found in the "\Brother bPAC3 SDK\Redist\" folder). It must be installed in the client machine to use the dll. Or this error will be thrown.

Comment: At first I downloaded pack from here: https://www.brother.co.jp/eng/dev/bpac/download/index.aspx , installed it, then I got into \Brother bPAC3 SDK\Redist\ folder and ran installation from there. It worked after reboot. There is 64bit and 32bit versions, I had to install both

Answer (score 1):

I received the same error on a application i wrote for work when i started using .net 4. That looks like  sample code they provide in there SDK. When i changed it to not check for the open path, i was able to get it to work.

Additionally, make sure you have the latest drivers installed with the Bpac printer. This is my altered code.

```
  Dim path As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath
  Dim doc As New bpac.Document
    doc = CreateObject("bpac.Document")
    doc.SetPrinter(doc.GetPrinterName().ToString, True)

    doc.Open(path + "/TesterLabel.lbx")
    doc.GetObject("objTicket").Text = lstTickets.Items.Item(0).ToString
    doc.GetObject("objTest").Text = issue
    doc.GetObject("objClaim").Text = strIssue
    doc.DoPrint(PrintOptionConstants.bpoDefault, "")
    doc.EndPrint()
    doc.Close()
```

Comment: I am getting the error when creating the bpac.document object. It isn't even getting to the open line.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to install the Printer in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

For me the trick was to install the right version of the SDK [SDK Version](http://www.brother.com/product/dev/label/bpac/download/bsdkw30015eu/index.htm) after that I installed the client drivers and it worked

Answer (score 0):

For me it was setting the target framework to .Net 4.0. I am using Brothers SDK: 3.3.001 (64-bit ver.) released 07/07/2020

Answer (score 0):

i've solved with Project > Properties > Build Tab > Target CPU anycpu - target destination cpu any cpu.
remember see properties setup project.